# VMware Workstation - Xrandr: Can't open display

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux, vmware-workstation, xrandr

I'm stuck trying to make Sway work on a fresh installation of arch linux, running on VMware Workstation 16. It looks like there is no Virtual-1 display that I specified in advance for Sway's config. When I try to run `xrandr` command, I can only see "Can't open display" response.

[Sway error log before restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2irPL.png)

Comment: Did you install VMware Tools in the Guest Machine - this is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I installed only Open VM Ware Tools. Should I also install Official VM Ware Tools from step 4 https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/VMware/Install_Arch_Linux_as_a_guest#Open-VM-Tools ?

Comment: Yes!   You should install the VMware supplied tools.

Comment: Done. Still no screen detected. vmwaretools service is running and for example I'm able to use shared folders without any problems. I also tried to install and run openbox which I used till now, but the error is same: `Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY environment variable`

Comment: Edit: Openbox works just fine after adding `exec openbox-session` to .xinitrc. Using `exec sway` fixes nothing. I'll probably just stick with openbox once again and try some i3 window manager derivate later.